# How to represent interdependency of information based on positions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, experimental-physics, quantum-information

If Information encoded on the surface of a black hole we can say information in side  the black hole is because the relevant information on the surface and information on the surface is because relevant information inside the black hole. this is just an example for the idea.  I wanna know is there anyway we can generalize this idea to a mathematical formula that, object is in some where else in (position $x$)  and the same information about that object as bits are existing some where else ($y$)? one way i thought was this
$H|si> = h|si>$  that $H$ contains the list of eigenvalues and the $h$ represent the current eigenvalue of the state. and the current value of $h$ is there because its also in the operator. (but this doesn't  has to be in the form of quantum mechanics. just for more abstract model.)  is this ring any bells?

Comment: The “surface” of a black hole is a door to the future. The inside of a black hole is in the future relative to the “surface”. For this reason, the information on the “surface” cannot depend on the information inside. Similarly, you cannot know today which number wins Poweball tomorrow. Information cannot travel back in time.